# How do I xml encode UTF8 characters in Oracle?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I'm using `dbms_xmlgen` to help generate my `XML` file. However it is not encoding my `chr(50093)` value.
When I save output to a file and view the file using IE9, I get the following message from IE9

```
An invalid character was found in text content. 
Error processing resource 'file:c/temp/XML_analysis/xml_aaa.xml'.

D
```

Here's my sample work:

```
 set serveroutput on;
 declare 
 cursor error_item is
 with error_row as
 (select 'D' || chr(50093) || 'a' as lname from dual)
  select lname from error_row;

 line1 varchar2(100) :=  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
 line2 varchar2(100) := '<word>';
 line3 varchar2(100);
 line4 varchar2(100) := '</word>';

 begin

 open error_item;
 fetch error_item into line3;
 close error_item;
 line3 := dbms_xmlgen.convert(line3);
 dbms_output.put_line(line1);
 dbms_output.put_line(line2);
 dbms_output.put_line(line3);
 dbms_output.put_line(line4);

 end;
```

I've consulted this [Orafaq.com](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_XMLGEN) site.

**Questions:**

1. Why won't `dbms_xmlgen.convert` encode `chr(50093)`?
2. Where can I learn more about how use Oracle methods to xml encode UTF8 character sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to encode your characters.

1. Reference sites such as [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ed/index.htm)
2. Determine your decimal encoding value. In this case, chr(50093), the Latin small letter I acute, has the decimal encoding value of 237.
3. Prepend 237 with the `&#` characters and append with a `;`.  In Oracle, you can do this with replace() as in `replace('string with characters',chr(50093),'&#237;'`

In this case, replace your `line3` assignment statement with

`line3 := replace(line3,chr(50093),'&#237;');`

You should be able to read the output in an XML reader.